# select form with multiple values and names in HTML

Tags: html, forms, select

Is it possible, that one option in a select form returns 2 values with 2 names?
I have f.e.:

```
<form name="form1" action="Servlet1" method="get">
    <select class="class1" name="name1" onChange="javascript:document.form1.submit();">
        <option value="value1">Test1</option>
        <option value="value2">Test2</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

and if someone klicks on Test1 I want the form to return name1=value1&name2=value2, not just one value.

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want all values if user only clicks one? Or do you mean you want to allow multiple values to be selected? Then use [`multiple`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select#attr-multiple) attribute.

Comment: no multiple selection. I just want multiple values when the user klicks one option.
My example is not the best, every option has to have ther own 2 values.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of approaches you could take to this.

The simplest is just to handle it with a look up on the server.

```
my %values = (
    value1 => { foo => 1, bar => 2 },
    value2 => { foo => 3, bar => 4 },
)

my $select_value = $q->param('name1');
my $foo = $values{$select_value}->{foo};
my $bar = $values{$select_value}->{bar};
```

---

Alternatively, use a structured data format (such as JSON) and encode it in the value:

```
<option value="{&quot;bar&quot;:2,&quot;foo&quot;:1}">Test1</option>
```

and then decode it on the server:

```
my $select_value = $q->param('name1');
my $decoded_value = from_json($select_value);
my $foo = $decoded_value->{foo};
my $bar = $decoded_value->{bar};
```

---

You could also apply a stack of client side JavaScript to generate hidden inputs with DOM when the form is submitted, but I wouldn't recommend that approach.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the best way, but you can always put both values in one value attribute. For example, you could try:

```
<select>
  <option value="name1.name2">Test1
  <option value="...">Test2
</select>
```

Then, you would parse out the different values in javascript.

And here's a fun fact: you don't need  tags in HTML 5. The browser will close the elements for you!